# s3sync not work with ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

I tried to upload my backups to amazon s3 using s3sync version 1.2.6
it dont work and I got this error

/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- md5 (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from s3sync.rb:23:in `<module:S3sync>'
    from s3sync.rb:11:in`'

ruby version is 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest version of s3sync. The version you're using is no longer supported:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/ServEdge_pub/s3sync/s3sync.tar.gz

"md5" is not a gem, it may be an old dependency that no longer exists. My first thought was to `gem install md5` but it doesn't find that gem in any repo. The above referenced gem now uses sha1 instead of md5.

Comment: @Eman that doesn't make sense. The new version doesn't use md5, it uses sha1. Did you uninstall the old version? restarted your server?

Comment: I used this package https://github.com/aproxacs/s3sync.  it works well but if uploading directory is bigger than 2 G it failed.

Comment: Sounds like it solved your error. Now that's a new problem, probably some s3 config you might need to do in aws. post a new question with more details, error messages etc